# Rails - Save an UTF-8 string with PostgreSQL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, encoding

How would I save an UTF-8 string to a model with Postgresql ?

I don't understand the console behaviour when doing something like so :

```
User.first.first_name
=> "ᚠᛇᚻ᛫ᛒᛦᚦ᛫ᚠᚱᚩᚠᚢᚱ᛫ᚠᛁᚱᚪ᛫ᚷᛖᚻᚹᛦᛚᚳᚢᛗ"

User.first.first_name.encoding
=> #<Encoding:UTF-8>
```

yields exactly what I want, but :

```
"ᚠᛇᚻ᛫ᛒᛦᚦ᛫ᚠᚱᚩᚠᚢᚱ᛫ᚠᛁᚱᚪ᛫ᚷᛖᚻᚹᛦᛚᚳᚢᛗ"
=> ""

"ᚠᛇᚻ᛫ᛒᛦᚦ᛫ᚠᚱᚩᚠᚢᚱ᛫ᚠᛁᚱᚪ᛫ᚷᛖᚻᚹᛦᛚᚳᚢᛗ".encoding
=> #<Encoding:UTF-8>
```

Both strings have the same encoding, but I can't display it in the second example (it yields an empty string), even though both objects have the same encoding.

This means that if I want to do something like :

```
User.first.update(first_name: "ᚠᛇᚻ᛫ᛒᛦᚦ᛫ᚠᚱᚩᚠᚢᚱ᛫ᚠᛁᚱᚪ᛫ᚷᛖᚻᚹᛦᛚᚳᚢᛗ")
=> true
```

it succeeds, but `first_name` will be set to an empty string, instead of the one I want.

In a psql console, the following statement will work and set the correct data :

```
UPDATE users SET first_name = 'ᚠᛇᚻ᛫ᛒᛦᚦ᛫ᚠᚱᚩᚠᚢᚱ᛫ᚠᛁᚱᚪ᛫ᚷᛖᚻᚹᛦᛚᚳᚢᛗ'
```

How would I proceed to set the user's first name to an UTF8 string with ruby ?

Comment: Why does your `"ᚠᛇᚻ᛫ᛒᛦᚦ᛫ᚠᚱᚩᚠᚢᚱ᛫ᚠᛁᚱᚪ᛫ᚷᛖᚻᚹᛦᛚᚳᚢᛗ"` result in `""`? I cannot reproduce that.

Comment: I would like to know why indeed

Comment: What does `"ᚠᛇᚻ᛫ᛒᛦᚦ᛫ᚠᚱᚩᚠᚢᚱ᛫ᚠᛁᚱᚪ᛫ᚷᛖᚻᚹᛦᛚᚳᚢᛗ".codepoints` return? (for the string literal that results in `""`)

Comment: @Stefan it returns an empty array

Comment: Seems like the characters are just being ignored. Could be an issue with your terminal or IRB setup. Try putting the code into a file and execute that.

Comment: Ditto, can't replicate. Can you give as much details about your system as possible? OS, OS version, which terminal you're using, Ruby version, content of your `.irbrc`... Also, can you try if the machine is freshly-booted it still does the same?

Comment: `.irbc` doesn't exist. I'm using `pry`, and `.pryrc` contains this one line : `Pry.color = true` OS : High Sierra 10.13.6, using iTerm2

Comment: That's weird; did you try to run it from a file as @Stefan suggested? Also, which Ruby version are you using?

Comment: Running `puts "ᚠᛇᚻ᛫ᛒᛦᚦ᛫ᚠᚱᚩᚠᚢᚱ᛫ᚠᛁᚱᚪ᛫ᚷᛖᚻᚹᛦᛚᚳᚢᛗ"` from a file outputs the correct result, so it's definitely an encoding issue with Pry and IRB (I tried with both)

Comment: @Kernael what happens if you run `ruby -e 'puts "ᚠᛇᚻ᛫ᛒᛦᚦ᛫ᚠᚱᚩᚠᚢᚱ᛫ᚠᛁᚱᚪ᛫ᚷᛖᚻᚹᛦᛚᚳᚢᛗ"'` from the terminal?

Comment: @Stefan It works as intended, the string is correctly printed

Comment: @Kernael okay, so it's not your terminal (and not Ruby). Maybe a broken readline installation?

Comment: `brew reinstall readline` doesn't fix the problem, how would I debug this further ?

Comment: Reinstalling Ruby with ```RUBY_CONFIGURE_OPTS="--with-readline-dir=`brew --prefix readline`" rbenv install 2.3.7``` and adding `rb-readline` to the Gemfile fixed the problem, thank you for your time !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case this happens to someone else, the problem can be fixed with :

- reinstalling ruby like so (Mac) :

```
RUBY_CONFIGURE_OPTS="--with-readline-dir=`brew --prefix readline`" rbenv install 2.3.7
```

- removing `rb-readline` from the development group of the Gemfile

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to force the encoding?

```
User.first.update(first_name: "ᚠᛇᚻ᛫ᛒᛦᚦ᛫ᚠᚱᚩᚠᚢᚱ᛫ᚠᛁᚱᚪ᛫ᚷᛖᚻᚹᛦᛚᚳᚢᛗ".force_encoding("UTF-8"))
```

Comment: Yes, it doesn't change the result, both `"ᚠᛇᚻ᛫ᛒᛦᚦ᛫ᚠᚱᚩᚠᚢᚱ᛫ᚠᛁᚱᚪ᛫ᚷᛖᚻᚹᛦᛚᚳᚢᛗ".force_encoding('utf-8')` and `User.first.update(first_name: "ᚠᛇᚻ᛫ᛒᛦᚦ᛫ᚠᚱᚩᚠᚢᚱ᛫ᚠᛁᚱᚪ᛫ᚷᛖᚻᚹᛦᛚᚳᚢᛗ".force_encoding('utf-8'))` yields `''`

Comment: Are you using Rails / just Ruby with some ORM?  Maybe in the adapter settings for the driver set to unicode?

Comment: I'm using Rails and ActiveRecord, I have `encoding: utf8` in **config/database.yml**. I've also tried to set `config.encoding = 'utf-8'` in **config/application.rb**

Comment: What's the default locale of the machine?  Type locale at the prompt.

Comment: `locale` returns : 

```LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"```

Comment: Stumped - let me see if I can replicate.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182090/discussion-between-cherrysoft-and-kernael).

Comment: Hey, I have tried to replicate on my machine and I cannot.  I done insert with Postgres and retrieve with AR in console.  Create with AR in console with force UTF-8 and without and retrieved in console and I retrieve the desired characters.  Would it help if I provide you some versions (Rails, Ruby etc.)?